Manipulate the location of the histogram/Area plot in PineScript 5
I am trying to merge 2 indicators in one to enhance the real estate of my chart. both are plotted as area or histograms using Plot() The issue I am facing is that Plot() itself doesn't have the location.top or location.bottom which would make it happen.
Attached is an example of the type of plots I am hoping to make.I simply want the first indicator to start from 0 and pointing upward ( location.bottom) and the 2nd indicator to start from say 100 and pointing down (location.top)
I tried Plotshape() but it doesn't allow histogram or area style.
my first indicator plotting code:
plot(testedShrk, color=shrk <= 0 ? color.new(#ff5252, 60): color.new(#4caf4f, 60),style = plot.style_area)

and the 2nd indicator's plotting code:
plot(testedRSI, "RSI Column", barColor, 1, plot.style_area)

Any help would be really appreciated

